# Google Apps Script multiple IF statements in an onEdit function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets

### Background

I'm trying to write a script that will check two different cells to see if the checkbox has been checked. So, it would first check one cell (AL4) to see if the value is true, and then a different cell (Q4) to see if the value is true. If the value is true, then it will run a different function.

Both of the cells I am checking are in the same sheet, "Dashboard", so it doesn't have to find different sheet names. I've been different ways to get it to check the different cells by using .getcolumn and .getrow commands but I've had some trouble with that too. I've also run into some problems where it will ignore the if statement and run the function on every edit and not just when the two cells are checked.

How can I get an if and else if statement to work in the same onEdit function?

### Current Script

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Dashboard"
  var range = e.range;
  
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getA1Notation() != "AL4" || !range.isChecked()) {
    return;
    
    RefreshCheckmark2();
  } else if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != sheetName || range.getA1Notation() != "Q4" || !range.isChecked()) {
    return;
    
    InverseYieldRefresh();
  }
}
```

Also, the above code is completely functional if you remove the else if statement and the brackets after the first If statement.

Ideally I would like to be able to add more else if statements so that it can check more cells because I like to have checkboxes run commands and if my understanding is correct, you can't have more than one onEdit function in a single spreadsheet.

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do right now is to check if it is not AL4 or Q4 rather than checking if it is AL4 or Q4. Also, in your current code, you use `return;` before running any function so it would really skip running the function even if it goes in your if-statement. You can try this code below:

```
function onEdit(e) {
   const sheetName = "Dashboard"
   var range = e.range;
  
   if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == sheetName && range.getA1Notation() == "AL4" && range.isChecked()) {
      RefreshCheckmark2();
  } 
  else if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() == sheetName && range.getA1Notation() == "Q4" && range.isChecked()) {
      InverseYieldRefresh();
  }
}
```

I only changed the conditions to make it check if it is AL4 or Q4 then removed the `return;` to make the functions inside the if-statements run once conditions are satisfied.

Let me know if this solves your problem.